# iPhone Mobile Safari, How many max parallel http connections?

Tags: iphone, http, mobile-safari

I would like to use parallel AJAX HTTP requests with iPhone Mobile Safari (OS4).
What is the max number of parallel connections?

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, Safari uses at most 4 connections to the same server, but you can test it yourself using [this little test case](http://www.spasche.net/files/parallel_connections/) (if you have access to an iPhone, of course).

Answer (score 2):

[Test site provided by Marcel](http://www.spasche.net/files/parallel_connections/) returned 6 connections on my iPhone 3GS.

Comment: Android 2.1 - 4 connections, Opera Mobile 11 - 2 connections, Firefox Mobile - 4 connections, iPod Touch 4.3 - 6 connections

Comment: Both Safari and Chrome on iPhone 4 (iOS 6) report 6 concurrent connections.

Comment: For me - 0 simultaneous connections on iPad Safari, 6 on Chrome (Desktop).