# Ajax error with JQuery on iPad

Tags: jquery, ajax, ipad

We have a problem in one of our Production web apps, but only on **iPad/iOS8**.

Basically, in our application, the user is adding products to his cart, by tapping on images that represent different products. When an image gets tapped, the product is "selected" and an ajax asynchronous call is made; this call updates our cart. Each asynchronous call lasts something like 5-10 seconds.

Problem occurs (but only on iPad, not on Chrome desktop, etc.) when the user clicks many times in sequence. Then, the n-th ajax call fails with "error 0". **Note**: we can't block a second ajax call when one is already in execution (as some answers would suggest), because the cart wouldn't be updated properly.

I've tracked down this behaviour in a jsFiddle example you can find here:

http://jsfiddle.net/oc1ktv6u/30/

```
function updateCart()
{
var data = {
        json: $.toJSON({
            text: 'some text',
            array: [1, 2, 'three'],
            object: {
                par1: 'another text',
                par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
                par3: {}
            }
        }),
        delay: Math.round(Math.random()*12)
}

$.ajax({
    url:"/echo/json/",
    data:data,
    type:"POST",
    success:function(response)
    {
       $(".target").append("+");
    },
    error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
    {
        alert("There was an error in the ajax call: ["+xhr.status+"] ["+thrownError+"]");
    }
});

}
```

My main question is:

- Why is this happening (and why, apparently, only on iPad/Safari)?

Comment: Check this thread for connection limitations

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940559/iphone-mobile-safari-how-many-max-parallel-http-connections

Comment: This error can be reproduced in your fiddle. Click the link and try to refresh jsfiddle.net page on your browser. Your error message will appear on alert. I think it is something other than parallel connections. I think the delay is causing this error. Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oc1ktv6u/42/

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers have mentioned you should have a queue to handle these request and make sure they are being handled in the order they are created:

```
var active = false;
var requests = [];

var updateCart = function (data) {
if(active) {
    requests.push(data);
} else {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            active = true;
            //show loading on the cart symbol or something to tell the user there is a process going on, UX goodness
        },
        success : function() {
            active = false;
            if(requests.length > 0) {
                next = requests.shift();
                updateCart(next);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

This site seems to give some insight into the number of active connections that are available at one time and you can test it out on your iPad http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network

I ran it on my own and it mentioned 17 max connections, but I am also curious about the network you are using with these iPads, if it is slower, say on 3G or Edge, than these connect could back up rather quickly. I was testing my iPad on Wifi and was unable to reproduce your error on the Fiddle. Hopefully this helps at least diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which iPad are you using (version and version of the OS)?. To reproduce the error, I have to tap really fast on the link and for about 50-100 times. I'm on normal WiFi.

Comment: My iPad is an Air (1st Gen) and is on iOS 8.1. I honestly did not attempt 50-100 clicks, maybe 30-50 although that seems very excessive for a Web App page unless it was some sort of game. I would suggest if you wanted to test something like this further beyond manual interaction would be to use a Testing Suite like Selenium for Firefox or Sahi - but again, this seems like a lot of processing that would either be handled by a queueing system, or a process that handles adding multiple items to the cart at once, instead of one by one.

Comment: Unfortunately this happened in real life on one of our production apps: someone tapped 50 times in a row on an iPad. But you know, software must be robust and our mission as developers is to handle even such strange corner cases.

Comment: Agreed, thus why i recommend scripts to recreate this and the code to handle the excess of requests coming in. If you want every click to be handled. Also I'm curious as to why every call would last 5-10 seconds, that seems like a lot of time to process adding something to a cart. Maybe consider optimizing the back end code as well to allow these requests to be completed faster. The Code Review Stack Exchange could help with that. Good Luck!

Comment: The 5-10 seconds on the back-end answer depend by an external system that handles our catalog and prices. We've already optimized this calls in the mean time, and lowered response times down to 2 seconds. So, now the "many clicks" problem is mitigated, but it's still present. Now we'll implement the "queue" strategy on iPad, even if a connection pool of async requests would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

1. block the click when the ajax is active
2. use preventDefault to not follow the link

```
 Please click <a href="#" id="aia">here</a> many times on iPad/Safari.
  <div class='target'>
      Result:
  </div>
```

```
$(function() {
  var active = false;
  $("#aia").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (active) return;
    active=true;
    var data = {
      json: $.toJSON({
        text: 'some text',
        array: [1, 2, 'three'],
        object: {
            par1: 'another text',
            par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
            par3: {}
        }
      }),
      delay: Math.round(Math.random()*12)
   }

   $.ajax({
     url:"/echo/json/",
     data:data,
     type:"POST",
     success:function(response) {
       $(".target").append("+");
       active=false;
     },
     error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
      alert("There was an error in the ajax call: ["+xhr.status+"] ["+thrownError+"]");
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Hello, I want the call to fire even if another call is already running. This because in our real application the anchor is not a link but an on/off image.

Comment: Then you need to stack the calls. Have a look for queue and promise, but look at the date of the suggestion too

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the reason of this behaviour on iPad?

Comment: No, Could be number of simultaneous http requests allowed or such. Anyway it is not a good idea to do simultaneous http requests on any device

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
var xhr = null;

function aia(){
    if (xhr == null)
        xhr = $.ajax({
            //...
            success: function(data){
                xhr = null;
            }
            //...
        });
}
```

Comment: No, sorry, probably my question was unclear. The ajax call must be done even if another call is already running.

Comment: In my opinion, status 0 means the xhr request has been canceled or the connection has been interrupted because of some reasons. So, have you tried to limit the number of simultaneous ajax requests by creating some kind of queue ?

Comment: Yes, we've been thinking of a queue, probably it would work. It would be interesting to know, though, why the request gets cancelled (why only on the iPad?) and if we're hitting some sort of limit.

Answer (score 0):

Working with latest versions of jquery in the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/oc1ktv6u/41/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    Please click <a href="#" id="js">here</a> many times on iPad/Safari.
    <div class='target'>
        Result:
    </div>
    <br />
        <div id='log'>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var i=0;
$('#js').on('touchstart click',function() {
          var data = {
            text: 'some text',
            array: [1, 2, 'three'],
            object: {
                par1: 'another text',
                par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
                par3: {}
            }
        }
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);          
var request = $.ajax({
url:"/echo/json/",
type: "POST",
data: jsondata,
dataType: "json"
});
request.done(function( msg ) {
$(".target").append("+");
   i++;
$( "#log" ).html( 'clicked '+ i + 'times');
});
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
});
```

Comment: Is there a real need for delay? What is the purpose of the delay in the first place?

Comment: Yes. The problem arises with concurrent connections. If you remove the delay, there is no concurrency.

Comment: Then you must map each and every connection and limit it to each browser's limit, after detecting browser.